# Images are not getting displayed in android xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to design as shown in below figure,i have a linear layout,inside that i am adding two images,over each image i am adding text view.But as per below code image doesnt even appear in xml file(i have added image in  drawable folder),What i am missing here?Please help me..

[image]

.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#C5C5C5">
    <TextView
        android:text="Desing view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="#c5c5c5">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try replacing img with ic_launcher icon and check is it showing or not? also put your activity code here.

Comment: I try your code,by just replacing img to ic-launcher it is working fine.I think there is a problem in your image.

Comment: @Silvans Solanki  yes,if i replace img other than that(smaller in width than used image) it is working,but for this particular image,image is not visible in xml.Why is it?is it because of image width and height?i also tried giving wrap_content ,at this time also no image appears.

Comment: @sumit singh yes you are right.What could be the problem in image.It is not accepting bigger image

Comment: may be those image are corrupt or, if it is bigger in size then it should give you error in your logcat. BitmapOutOfMemory, please check your logcat for more info.

Comment: try `TextView` and set `android:background="@drawable/your_image"`

Comment: Is this your original and actual complete XML file? or you done any modification before pasting in Question. I doubt. Please put whole actual XML code here. because the above given XML is just fine.